# SSRS adding formula to Interval Offset property

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am trying to workout the formula for the following. Could someone please help.

```
= if ReportingMonth= 10, then interval offset = 3, 
   If ReportingMonth = 11 then interval offset = 1
  If ReportingMonth = 12 then interval offset = 2
```

Note: ReportingMonth is the Report variable.

This needs to be for all 12 months.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide some more information. Without knowing anything about your dataset, it seems like it would be easier to do this in SQL. Pass in the data parameter, then analyze and offset within SQL. If this isn't an option, and you don't know how to get the month, you can use this in VBA:

```
thisMonth = Month(thisDate)
```

And then you can offset accordingly. I'm assuming here that you're trying to offset the month, based on the date parameter. Please correct me and provide more information if I'm wrong.